# Is the quantity $\frac{\partial v^a}{\partial x^b}$ a tensor?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

I would like to understand something about tensors.

If I take the following quantity : $\frac{\partial v^a}{\partial x^b}$ is it a tensor in a general case ?

I think it depends on the class of transformations allowed but I am not sure.

To illustrate what I mean :

$$ \frac{\partial v^a}{\partial x^b} = \frac{\partial \widetilde{v}^i \frac{\partial v^a}{\partial \widetilde{x}^i}}{\partial x^b}=\frac{\partial y^k}{\partial x^b}\frac{\partial [\widetilde{v}^i \frac{\partial v^a}{\partial \widetilde{x}^i}]}{\partial y^k}$$

It will be a tensor if it transforms "well", so if :

$$ \frac{\partial v^a}{\partial x^b} = \frac{\partial y^k}{\partial x^b} \frac{\partial v^a}{\partial \widetilde{x}^i} \frac{\partial \widetilde{v}^i }{\partial y^k}$$

So in particular, we have to do transformations such as :

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial y^k}\frac{\partial v^a}{\partial \widetilde{x}^i}=0 $$

To ensure that we indeed work with tensors 1 contravariant and 1 covariant.

Is my understanding correct ? (probably not, that's why I am asking :D )

Comment: It's not a tensor in curvilinear coordinates, only in rectilinear coordinates.

Comment: It's not clear how to interpret your comment, @md2perpe. Isn't a tensor something that is invariant under all coordinates transformation?

Comment: If the various $v^a$ are scalar functions of coordinates $x^b$, then yes. If they are the components of a vector field, then no. It depends on what you mean by "a general case". It really depends on what the variables represent.

Comment: I rephrase: The entity transforms as a tensor when changing between rectilinear coordinates, but not when changing between general (curvilinear) coordinates.

Comment: The symbol $\frac{\partial v^a}{\partial x^b}$ does not represent a tensor. However, there is the covariant derivative, $\nabla_bv^a$, which is a tensor. In fact, it's defined so that it is _the_ tensor for which $\nabla_bv^a = \frac{\partial v^a}{\partial x^b}$ in standard, Euclidean coordinates in Euclidean space.

Comment: @BenMcKay Why it would'nt be a tensor if it is components of a vector field ? What would that change ?

Comment: @md2perpe so if I understand what you meant, it is a tensor in rectilinear coordinates only because it is the only case where $\frac{\partial \frac{\partial v^a}{\partial x^i}}{\partial y^k}=0$ right ? (So in fact you just said what I wrote differently ?)

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: As stated, the question isn't well-posed. From the "components" viewpoint, a tensor is _an assignment, to each coordinate system, of an indexed collection of functions satisfying transformation rules_. You've only specified a set of functions in _one_ coordinate system.

Comment: @BenMcKay I think I understood your comment in fact but I would like a confirmation. If it is a scalar it is a tensor as scalars don't change under change of coordinates (in opposite of vectors). Thus $\frac{\partial v^a}{\partial x^b}=\frac{\partial v^a}{\partial y^k} \frac{\partial y^k}{\partial x^b}$, so no problem if $v^a$ is a scalar (it is the good transformation law). But if it is a vector I have the problematic $v^a=v'^k \frac{\partial x^a}{\partial y^k}$ that will introduce an extra derivative which will cause the problem as written in my previous comment. That was what you meant ???

Comment: @StarBucK: yes, that is what I meant, perhaps said more clearly by Andrew D. Hwang.